# Replicating GRG Nonlinear optimization in R

Tags: r, excel, solver, nonlinear-optimization, nlopt

```
   `# objective function
      eval_f0 <-function(x) {

          v=rep(0,length(x))
            for (i in 1:length(x)){
           v[i]=tab$beta0[i]+((tab$new.beta[i]*tab$avg.current.adstock[i]* 
       ((x[i]/tab$media.spends[i])^tab$dr[i])))
        }
      return(mean(v))
        }
      # constraint function
      eval_g0 <- function(x) {
      constr <- x
       return(constr)
        }

        eval_g1 <- function(x){
         h <- sum(x)-sum(tab$media.spends)*1.01
          return(h)
         }

         res1 <- nloptr( x0=tab$lower.limt,
            eval_f=eval_f0,
            lb = tab$lower.limt,
            ub = tab$upper.limt,
            eval_g_ineq = eval_g0,
            eval_g_eq = eval_g1,
            opts = list("algorithm"="NLOPT_GN_ISRES"
                        ,maxeval=100000,xtol_abs=1e-8))


 `
```

I am trying to replicate GRG non-linear optimization problem from excel solver in R using nloptr, but the result is nowhere near to it.Has anyone tried the same?

I also tried solnp but no luck. Please share the package information for getting the same results as excel GRG Nonlinear optimization.

Comment: Please post whatever you have tried so others can help

Comment: @Tung I have added the code.Please see if you can help

Comment: There is no R package that precisely mimics what GRG is doing. You can improve things by choosing a gradient method instead of a heuristic and by actually providing gradients.